# Looking for an elegant proof of $\det(A) = \det(A^t)$ without Schur decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Looking for an elegant proof of $\det(\textbf{A}) = \det(\textbf{A}^{t})$ without Schur decomposition.

**Proof 1 with Schur decomposition**
$$\textbf{A} = \textbf{P}^{t}\Delta\textbf{P} \implies\textbf{A}^{t} = (\textbf{P}^{t}\Delta\textbf{P})^{t} = \textbf{P}^{t}\Delta^{t}\textbf{P}$$
So, $\textbf{P}$  is unitary matrix, $\textbf{P}^{t}=\textbf{P}^{-1}$.
$$\det(\textbf{P})=\det(\textbf{P}^{t})= \det(\textbf{P}^{-1})$$
 $\Delta$ is upper triangular matrix.
$$\det(\Delta)=\det(\Delta^{t}) \implies   \det(\textbf{A})=\det(\textbf{A}^{t})$$

Comment: It's not really a proof, but you can say "Leibniz definition of determinant arbitrarily chose between rows and columns".

Comment: @DanielV That can be very easily transformed into a proof. Another proof is that this is trivial for diagonalizable matrices, and these are dense in the set of matrices. Another proof is that every matrix is similar to its transpose. etc. etc.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one proof, not sure if it's elegant or not.

Clearly $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^\mathrm{T}$ is, so we limit our proof to invertible matrices. Invertible matrices are products of elementary matrices and the determinants of elementary matrices are easily verified to be invariant under transpose. Hence the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with $v$ as its non-zero eigenvector then
$$
(A-\lambda I)v=0\implies v^T(A-\lambda I)^T=0\implies \det(A^T-\lambda I)=0
$$
Therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same and they have **the same geometric multiplicity**. For those class of matrices with the same algebraic and geometric multiplicities, we can say that  the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same in multiplicity too.

Again independently we can show that the determinant of $A$ is the product of its eigenvalues and hence:
$$
\det A=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=\det A^T.
$$
So we use the fact that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues to prove the result. Note that one should not use $\det A=\det A^T$ to prove that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues to avoid circularity.

Comment: Your first argument shows that the set of eigenvalues of the transpose is the same as the original matrix, but I'm not sure that it shows that the eigenvalues are equal up to multiplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, it does not show that they have the same algebraic multiplicity but the same geometric multiplicity. So the proof works only for those matrices with the same geometric and algebraic multiplicities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is quite what you're looking for, but:

For any map $f:V \to V$ with $n = \dim V$ finite, the induced map $\bar{f}:\bigwedge V^n \to \bigwedge V^n$ is a map on a one-dimensional space, and thus must be given by $\overline{f}(x) = \alpha x$ for some constant $\alpha$ (independent of a choice of basis); this constant $\alpha$ is by definition $\det f$. With the notation above, we have $\overline{A^t} = (\overline{A})^t$. It's then easy to verify directly that $\det(A^t) = \det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every square matrix $A$ has an LDU-factorization. That is if $A$ is a square matrix there is a lower-triangular matrix $L$, a diagonal matrix $D$, and an upper-triangular matrix $U$ such that $A=LDU$ and both $L$ and $U$ have 1s on their diagonals.

From this factorization, it is clear that $$\det(A)=\det(LDU)=\det L\cdot\det D\cdot\det U=\det U^T\cdot\det D^T\cdot\det L^T=\det(U^TD^TL^T)=\det(A^T)$$

The existence of this factorization can be derived in a way similar to how one finds the inverse of a matrix. Given $A$ construct the matrix $[A|I]$ and perform row reduction to make $A$ into an upper diagonal matrix. The resulting matrix on the right is the inverse of the matrix you want in the factorization. To get the upper diagonal matrix do the same thing with the row reduced matrix $A'$ on *top* of the identity matrix and perform column reduction. The resulting matrix on the bottom will be the inverse of matrix you want in the factorization.